# How to get the list of repository from AWS CodeCommit using AWS REST API call in Postman tool?

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-codecommit, aws-rest-api

I have to use AWS REST API to work with various cloud services. Initially, I'm trying in postman tool to fetch the list of repositories from AWS CodeCommit. I'm following this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_ListRepositories.html to accomplish my task. I have problem on setting the authorization for this API call. I have provided both access and secret keys and the region. I could not get the repository lists instead facing `503` network issue.

**UPDATE**

I'm facing the following error message

```
{
  "Output": {
    "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException"
  },
  "Version": "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. In Postman, select the POST method and put URL as 'https://codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/'
2. Go to Headers and add

- 'Content-Type' key and 'application/x-amz-json-1.1' as the value
- 'X-Amz-Target' key and 'CodeCommit_20150413.ListRepositories' as the value
- 'Host' key and 'codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' as the value

3. Go to the 'Authorization' tab and configure the AWS Signature type as follows:

- AccessKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
- SecretKey: xxxxxxxxxxxxx
- AWS Region: us-east-1

4. Go to 'Body' tab and type `{}`
5. Click 'Send' to test

### Note: Make sure to use correct region in all the place above (us-east-1 as example).